# roslaunch of dynamic reconfigure gui

Tags: ros, roslaunch, gui, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like the dyanmic reconfigure gui to launch automatically from the launch file rather than having to open up a new terminal and rosrun it separately. Does anyone know if this is possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9601/roslaunch-of-dynamic-reconfigure-gui/) by [Gideon](https://answers.ros.org/users/362/gideon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 239 on 2011-03-29

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding the following node element should work:

```
<node name="reconfigure_gui" pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="reconfigure_gui" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8